# Firefox redirects to browser's homepage by scanning a barcode

Tags: firefox, barcode-scanner

I want to use an barcode scanner, to scan EAN codes. The scanned code will be automatically transferred to a form of the web page currently opened in firefox.

But: Firefox redirects to the configured homepage by scanning a code. How can I change this configuration?

Comment: So … some hardware (unspecified) is sending some signal to the computer which is being interpreted somehow (how? We don't know. Maybe it is through a custom driver. Maybe it just pretends to be a keyboard). If we assume it is pretending to be a keyboard, then it will be sending some key strokes (we don't know which ones) to wherever the focus is (maybe that's the address bar, maybe it is some input, maybe it is something else) which might be read by some JavaScript (no code has been shared). The question is missing rather a lot of important information.

Comment: The scanner pretends to be a keyboard, but it doesn't matter where the focus is.

Comment: "but it doesn't matter where the focus is" — Click in the search box at the top of this page. Type something. Then click in the address bar of your browser and type something. **It matters where the focus is**.

Comment: But not for the scanner. It allways redirects to browser's homepage by scanning from any web page, with focused form fields, whatever.

Comment: Maybe it is sending the key strong combination to go to the homepage (Ctrl + H or something) but that seems unlikely. Of course, you still haven't told us what data *is* being sent by it.